# Introduction to Analysis: Continuity and Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

The following is a Theorem the instructor gave up.

> Let $f(x)$ be defined for $x \approx a$, and suppose that for all {$x_n$} such that $x_n \rightarrow a, x_n \neq a$, we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)$ = $\mathcal{L}$. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = \mathcal{L}$.

He skipped the proof for this and left it as an exercise. He stated the theorem is not very useful in proving $\lim f(x)$ exists, since we would have to examine all sequences converging to a. Anywho, he wants us to prove it by contrapositive, or contraposition if you prefer to call it this way.

From what I understand, I have to show that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) \neq \mathcal{L}$, then it is possible to find a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\rightarrow a$, yet $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) \neq \mathcal{L}$.

This is more a less my draft for the proof, still unsure of myself but it is a start:

Assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) \neq \mathcal{L}$, then $\forall\epsilon,\exists\delta$ such that $\vert x - a \vert < \delta$, but $f(x) \not\approx \mathcal{L}$.  Also, $x_n\approx a$ as $x_n \rightarrow a $ , then because but $f(x) \not\approx \mathcal{L}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) \neq \mathcal{L}$

Things that make me doubt, we do not know if a is continuous at all. Also, it is too short, does not seem strong enough, and I did not explicitly show that $f(x_n) \not\rightarrow L$.

Anywho, Thanks for taking the time to read. 
Thanks in advanced for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\not=L$. Then there exists some sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to a$ but $f(x_n)\not\to L$. This is the negation of the first part of the statement.